# Is it ok to register components in Windsor without specifying an interface?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Is it considered bad form to register components in Windsor without specifying an interface? i.e.

```
container.Register(Component.For<MyClass>().LifeStyle.Transient);
```

as opposed to...

```
container.Register(Component.For<IMyClass>().ImplementedBy<MyClass>().LifeStyle.Transient);
```

I understand the benefits of coding to an interface rather than a concrete implementation however we are finding that we now have lots of interfaces many of them are on classes that realistically will only ever have one implementation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it would be okay to register components without their interfaces, but **not for the reason you give**.

**Concrete dependencies**

It may happen that components depend on concrete classes. For instance, with the Entity Framework consumers should have the ObjectContext injected into them. That's a concrete class that still needs to be injected because it should be **shared** between several consumers.

Thus, given a consumer's constructor like this:

```
public FooRepository(FooObjectContext objectContext)
```

you would need to configure the container like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<FooObjectContext>());
```

The FooRepository **requests no interface** so it makes no sense registering an interface (even if one was available), but you must still register the concrete class because Windsor can **only resolve types explicitly registered**.

**Interfaces with only one implementation**

Then what about interfaces with only one implementation? Once again, the consumer decides the requirements.

Imagine that a consumer has this constructor:

```
public Ploeh(IBar bar)
```

The only way Castle Windsor will be able to resolve Ploeh is when you register IBar. Even if Bar is the only implementation of IBar, **this will not work**:

```
container.Register(Component.For<Bar>());
```

This doesn't work because IBar is never registered. Castle Windsor doesn't care that Bar implements IBar because it doesn't want to try to be smart on your behalf. You must tell it explicitly:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IBar>().ImplementedBy<Bar>());
```

This **maps** IBar to Bar.

**Registering both interfaces and concrete types**

Then what if you want to be able to resolve both the concrete type and the interface?

The problem with the previous example is that it will let you resolve IBar, but not Bar.

You can use the Forward method, or multigeneric overload of For to forward registrations:

```
container.Register(Component.For<Bar, IBar>().ImplementedBy<Bar>());
```

This lets you resolve **both** Bar and IBar.

Comment: another good example would be Controllers in a MVC application - you don't need to abstract them.

Comment: Yes, MVC Controllers are an even better example - I was just mired in some EF code, so that came to my mind first :)

Comment: Thanks Mark but what if I am the developer creating the Bar class should I make it have an interface IBar simply so that I can register in Windsor via the interface? Why not simply register Bar in Windsor and make Ploeh consume Bar?

Comment: That would circumvent loose coupling. If you do that, then why use a DI Container at all?

Comment: If the repository aceepts as dependency the base class DbContext, this works, but is it correct?
container.Register(Component.For<DbContext>().ImplementedBy<AllDomainContext>().LifestylePerWebRequest())